# 1-5% founding CTO equity?

Tags: communication, negotiation, startup, equity

I am a PhD candidate in a technical field who recently met two other folk of similar interest and embarked on an entrepreneurial endeavor. They are interested in starting a company that requires the promise of certain technical elements (which I know how to implement) applied to a scientific sector they are very knowledgeable in, and have created a business model   for but have no technical expertise and would like for me to help them build out their MVP. They have also stated that they will handle all the pitching (I also attend all business meetings and everything is transparent), and fuzzier business dealings that they hope will land us our Series A. Both of the cofounders have expertise in the scientific area of interest. The idea originated between the two of them, and one of them has built successful businesses and a successful network (which we will utilize for our product) in the region that we want to launch our product. The other cofounder shares the business responsibilities and helps in pitching ideas while facilitating business relationships with other projects and maintaining our day-to-day e.g. task management.

In exchange they have offered 1% equity plus monthly salary of $2k/month for the duration of our 3-month pre-seed to deliver a MVP as the founding CTO. Supposing we are able to land a successful Series A investment my equity will increase to 5% and salary will also increase. They have stated that their equity will decrease to accommodate new investors during this time as well.

Is this a fair deal? I initially took it as generous, as it is my first time undertaking a challenge of this magnitude (and they know this), and also because I understand their desire to hedge their risk in employing me since I am part-time (even though I give 40hr weeks, I have the PhD) and relatively inexperienced in this role. I also manage a small development team and my core responsibilities have been developing the technical roadmap for the medium to long-term, coding out the MVP, and ensuring that collaborations with other technical teams is feasible.

From what I have read online, it seems that the equity depends more or less on the type of involvement that one has and at what point in time, and the comments range from 1-10% being fair versus an equal part of the pie 33% for 3 founders. I feel I am early enough in this project to the point where I am helping in deciding many aspects of the project, while ensuring that everything decided is technically feasible. I am even helping them write our whitepaper. I am considering asking for no salary so that I may increase my equity percentage, as I believe in the product and would rather own more of the business than get paid but I am not sure if this is prudent, and if they would be insulted by my asking for more when they already feel they have been generous. If this is prudent, what would be a good equity % bump to ask for?

Comment: What are they bringing to the table? What are their qualifications? Why do they even deserve 1%, let alone 90+%? In any case, you should read this book: The Partnership Charter https://www.amazon.com/Partnership-Charter-Start-Right-Business/dp/0738208981/ It doesn't really answer your question regarding percentages, but it outlines some of the work you need to do before entering into a partnership with those two. A partnership is like marriage. You need to take it very seriously.

Comment: Also, if you really want 33% of the shares, you need to ask for way more than 33%.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks for the response - I have edited the question. My goal is not 33%, it is just to know if the 1-5% they offered is fair compensation for what I am doing, or if I should attempt to negotiate

Comment: "Supposing a successful Series A my equity will increase to 5% and salary will also increase." This part makes no sense to me. Getting the Series A funding is their job, not yours. Maybe no one should be getting more than 1% until they've been doing their job and proven their value, including them. Also, it will be much harder to convince the new investors that you need 5% after they inject the money into the venture. Let's be realistic. Have you vetted those two guys? Or are you taking them at their word that they know what they're doing?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I have not "vetted" them in the sense that I know what their equity amounts are, but I know of their reputation in the scientific field and that the business model they propose is credible. We already have been given pre-seed funding by an accelerator program aiming to help us develop our product for a Series A. What I implied above is that once the team obtains a Series A (which will probably have some dependence on a working MVP), my equity will increase, NOT that they will give me an equity increase if I get them a Series A. That is very much still their responsibility.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't sound too bad then. But if you really want to increase your percentage, you must explore your other options as well. If your opportunity cost is high, then you can more easily negotiate for more.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk thanks for your feedback. Can you elaborate on what you mean by my "other options"? Currently the success of their technical product does hinge on the work that I and the dev team I manage put into it. Would asking for an equity bump in return for no pay be acceptable here? If so, how should I calculate the equity bump I ask for?

Comment: Leverage comes from the power of being able to walk away. Would you be able to walk away if they said no to you about having a bigger share? That is the real question. By options, I mean can you find a good job at a bigger company with guaranteed income? Probably. If so, you have the power to walk away. Also, here is a different argument, if one of them has a heart attack tomorrow? Would his shares come back to the common pool? Probably not. Right? Everybody needs to be on a schedule, not just you.

Comment: Plus, there are other issues to consider, by only accepting 1%, you'd be relinquishing control of the company to both of them. So tell me, what happens if the one with the most shares decides to hire his unqualified girlfriend and his unqualified nephew, and give them shares. Would you be able to to stop him? No, probably not. That is why you need to read the book I mentioned. There are so many aspects of this that you haven't considered.

Comment: Also, that 5% equity after a series A, is that written in the contract? Or is that a verbal promise? After you read that book I suggested, you should look for an experienced lawyer to hire yourself. No doubt, the company has its own lawyer, but you need your own in this case.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I understand the need to be cautious, frankly the current distribution makes sense given their current full-time commitment and my part-time one - they may want to keep my share low (at least for the time being), but I aim to change this by proposing more of a cofounder role post-Series A when I can give a greater commitment.  I think something I've neglected to ask that I should is what the share distribution looks like, do you think it's better to get this information from them now or after we launch an MVP? Asking now seems pre-emptive, as we don't yet even have a product

Comment: The details as outlined above were sent in a document electronically signed by both cofounders. I didn't sign anything yet, so I figured now would be a good time to start looking into this.

Comment: To put it simply, you are not a founder, they two individuals you describe are founders.  You will be their CTO before Series A funding is acquired, and perhaps beyond that.  For your troubles you will be given a percentage of the company, and ther ownership will continue to grow, all that is pretty typical in the growth of a company. The whole premise of ownership of a company is, you forgo  getting paid today, for the potential larger payout tomorrow.  Only you can decide if the time you spend, is worth the potential payout, it's all about opportunity cost.

Comment: (continued briefly)...Take the history of Twitter, Facebook, Google, even Apple, and Microsoft.  You have the individuals who bootstrap the company into success (founders), and then hired individuals when the company's future perhaps wasn't certain (i.e. you in your example), and when everything aligned, the company succeeded.  Now you won't get a large part of the pie, you are not a founder after all, but a small piece of a valuable pie is....well, valuable.  Take those companies today, it's impossible to have that same piece of the pie as a regular stockholder, unless you were given stocks e

Comment: @Donald would foregoing salary compensation for the foreseeable future put me in the category of a founder? This is something that I am more than willing to do, I care more about ownership of the company than I do about a payday, as I feel like I've put in enough work for it to feel like it is my product as well. I also note that the founders are paying themselves in this first round, the same as they are paying me. It is only after acquiring a Series A that they will reduce their equity and salary compensation and increase mine.

Answer (score 4):

I think the decision you face is whether you see yourself in the future as a "much valued employee" or a "founder member" of this company.

By accepting 1% equity, and not attending the pitches, you are in the former category, and you may find yourself locked out of all the strategic decisions that the founders make. If you are happy with that, then fine, but I do wonder if that is under-valuing your skills, and you may end up being frustrated at the direction the company takes.

Conversely, you could decide that you want to be more involved in the creation of this company, since you feel that your technical expertise is an essential component of its success. If so, you need to make that clear now, and (for example) go to the pitches, and ask for a greater involvement in the decision-making, and hence a larger percentage of the equity.

Only you can decide which path is best, but just consider whether you'll become the person who, in 5 years time, grumbles about the company, saying "I worked really hard to make it a success, and look how they've treated me".

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The issue I face now is that the founders seem to have placed me in the former category, but my work output has so far been in the latter. At least this is how I feel about things. I am not sure that 5% equity is sufficient for my current contribution, but my question is how do I have this conversation with them before I have even built anything?  I guess I need to have a conversation with them on what the expectations are of a founder, given I still have the PhD on the side that they could invoke as me not being "committed enough"

Comment: I suppose that my initial idea - to take a reduction in compensation (or abandon compensation altogether) for a fixed period of time while we are starting up would be a good way to signal to them that I want to take on a more serious role?

Comment: It sounds like the founders are somewhat taking advantage of you, and by controlling the agenda, you could end up in a minor role. Don't just send them signals, you need to have a full cards-on-the-table discussion with them, not just in terms of salary & equity, but also your actual role in the company. I don't think the PhD should be an issue; in their pitches they'll probably be referencing your PhD-level technical expertise, so it is an asset for them. My personal opinion: go for it! If you stand up for yourself now, it could bring major rewards later.

Comment: thanks so much for the encouragement! I do think that this is a conversation that is desperately needed. It currently feels like limbo in terms of role/equity and it feels that while I am taking more of a backseat I am also putting in a lot of the work. The PhD has come up in our accelerator, with people asking about my time commitment. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a major factor in my equity, since it can also read as "someone who isn't fully committed to what the team is building and has other things going on". But I do think it'd be nice to get some clarity moving forward

Comment: @TravisCarpenter, Yeah, I agree with the other opinion. If you're a part-time worker who gets paid $2,000 per month, you're not a founder. At the same time, be careful what you're getting yourself into, if you're responsible for the MVP, you may end up working insane hours anyway.

Comment: Thanks @StephanBranczyk, this is the same rate that the founders are paying themselves in the pre-seed, but I would be more than willing to forego this pay to increase my equity, something that I am not yet sure is an option. I would actually forego salary compensation even into a Series A if it meant an increase in my equity and having a more meaningful role in the company. But as my work output currently stands I feel a bit like this hasn't been accounted for in my equity. So clarity from the founders directly would be nice.

Comment: It's not the money that is troublesome, it's the fact that you're not all the way in since you're keeping your current job. And don't get me wrong, I'm not suggesting that you quit your current job in order to join this startup. Startups are notoriously risky, even when they're based on a good idea. But because you're keeping your current job and an escape hatch for yourself, which I really don't blame you for, you really can't be considered at the same level in the startup as the two other guys (unless you have some other leverage that the startup absolutely needs from you).

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating an early stage start up is notoriously difficult. Some things to consider

1. IMO on first glance, that's a reasonable package: nothing sticks out as obviously bad, but of course a lot of that depends on the details
2. Make sure that your cash flow requirements are met and that you can live reasonably well on whatever salary they are paying
3. Do you like the people, the product and the market? This is "all-in" job, so if you have any personal reservations, you need to work through this first
4. Start ups are very unstructured and require a lot of improvisation and "going with the flow". Sometimes you solve complicated equations and sometimes you clean up the mess in the kitchen. Whatever needs to get done, needs to get done.
5. Make sure you understand all the typical equity mechanisms: options (ISO and NQ), RSU, grants, preferred shares, vesting, dilution, taxability. etc. A good book can help here. Example: [https://www.amazon.com/Consider-Your-Options-Equity-Compensation/dp/0979224896](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0979224896) (or whatever works in your country)
6. Then read your paperwork using the knowledge gained from. Alternatively have it looked over by a local labor lawyer or expert. Assess the risk of being diluted or pushed out.
7. Set realistic expectations. Most start ups fail. Make sure you are financially and emotionally ok with that outcome.
8. Read the business plan. There are typically a few discrete "exit points" that define when and how equity gets turned into cash. Run these scenario for your package and try to estimate with how much you could end up.

Your decision will be a weighted average of all these considerations. Good luck! I have worked for start ups and it was a) a lot of and b) overall financially successful.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar for your response! I think most notably in response to (3), I love the people and the project. While it is more-or-less a part-time thing for me, because I am passionate about the project I find myself contributing a lot more than what they perhaps expect of me, and I guess this is something I would like to have reflected in equity. I suppose the offer is for a CTO who is meant to be an employee more than a founder, so I guess I should clarify their expectations before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Like all things in life, it is a Negotiation.

Do you think that you will bring in more than 1% of value to the company? Or 5%?

You mentioned forgoing a Salary for a Higher percentage for a period of time - which is an option.

You could also talk with them about performance based equity increases - e.g. "If we hit goal X by time Y, then my percentage will increase to Z%" or similar.

Are there additional things you could contribute to the potential success of the business? For example Cash investment, Expertise recruitment, Other resources.

Without knowing the full details of both your work and the business itself, it's hard to say with certainty whether the percentages outlined are fair - On the face of it, the offer seems reasonable for a low percentage considering you aren't fronting up any cash and you aren't leveraging your existing sales network.

But you can always negotiate.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think I need to flesh out potential contribution-based equity increases with them before we move forward.